# Upload Photo to Facebook with HttpClient

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, apache-commons-httpclient

I am attempting to use the following code to upload a photo to Facebook using the Graph API.  I keep getting "Bad Request" but not sure why.  I can upload the photo just fine using curl with the same parameters.  I'm using Java with HttpClient.

```
    PostMethod filePost = new PostMethod('https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos');
    filePost.setParameter('access_token', 'my-access-token')
    filePost.setParameter('message', 'test image')

    filePost.getParams().setBooleanParameter(HttpMethodParams.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);
    try {
      println("Uploading " + file.getName() + " to 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos'");
      Part[] parts = [new FilePart('source', file.getName(), file)]
      filePost.setRequestEntity(new MultipartRequestEntity(parts, filePost.getParams()));
      HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
      client.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams().setConnectionTimeout(5000);
      int status = client.executeMethod(filePost);
      if (status == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        println(
                "Upload complete, response=" + filePost.getResponseBodyAsString()
        );
      } else {
        println(
                "Upload failed, response=" + HttpStatus.getStatusText(status)
        );
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      println("ERROR: " + ex.getClass().getName() + " " + ex.getMessage());
      ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      filePost.releaseConnection();
    }
```

UPDATE: More to this.  I grabbed some more info out the response and I am getting this:

{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."}}

But that doesn't seem right as I'm using the access token that facebook gives back to me after the authorize process.

Working curl code:

```
curl -F 'access_token=my-access-token' -F 'source=@/path/to/image.jpg' -F 'message=Some caption' https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos
```

Comment: Can you add your working curl code too?

Comment: Added to the bottom of the post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem. Instead of adding the params to the PostMethod, I needed to add the access_token and message to the Part[] array.  Full code:

```
    PostMethod filePost = new PostMethod('https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos');
    filePost.getParams().setBooleanParameter(HttpMethodParams.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);
    try {
      println("Uploading " + file.getName() + " to 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos'");
      Part[] parts = [new FilePart('source', file.getName(), file), new StringPart('access_token', "${facebookData.access_token}"), new StringPart('message', 'some message')]
      filePost.setRequestEntity(new MultipartRequestEntity(parts, filePost.getParams()));
      HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
      client.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams().setConnectionTimeout(5000);
      int status = client.executeMethod(filePost);
      if (status == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
        println("Upload complete, response=" + filePost.getResponseBodyAsString());
      } else {
        println("Upload failed, response=" + HttpStatus.getStatusText(status));
        // Create response
        StringBuilder notificationsSendResponse = new StringBuilder();
        byte[] byteArrayNotifications = new byte[4096];
        for (int n; (n = filePost.getResponseBodyAsStream().read(byteArrayNotifications)) != -1;) {
          notificationsSendResponse.append(new String(byteArrayNotifications, 0, n));
        }
        String notificationInfo = notificationsSendResponse.toString();
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      println("ERROR: " + ex.getClass().getName() + " " + ex.getMessage());
      ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      filePost.releaseConnection();
    }
```

Comment: I declared file but it's showing bad request as response ............................               Uploading bird.jpg to 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos'
Upload failed, response=Bad Request

Comment: This thread is 4.5 years old. It is highly likely that their API has changed and that this isn't relevant anymore.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the socialauth java api for uploading image through web application.

http://code.google.com/p/socialauth/

Answer (score 1):

this is the android version of method

```
  private void postOnFacebook() {
        try {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos");
            MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
            String base64Image = "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAIAAAACDbGyAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAASSURBVBhXY3gro4KMKOPLqAAAq/UdZuRmLacAAAAASUVORK5CYII=";
            byte[] imageData = Base64.decode(base64Image, 0);
            entity.addPart("access_token", new StringBody("your access token"));
            entity.addPart("message", new StringBody("test msg"));
            entity.addPart("source", new ByteArrayBody(imageData, "test"));
            CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
            httpPost.getParams().setBooleanParameter(USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);
            httpPost.setEntity(entity);
            HttpResponse resp = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity2 = resp.getEntity();
            if (entity != null) {
                String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity2);
                responseBody.toString();
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {

            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```