# The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Tags: java, facebook, access-token

I am developing a simple java program to post automatically (articles) to my facebook fun page. I have created an app and have got an access_token using url : https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=CLIENR_SECRET. I use this java code to post to fun page wall :

```
String url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" + PAGE_ID + "/feed"
List<NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("access_token", accessToken));
nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", item.getTitle()));
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost(url);
httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpost);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

I got this error:

```
{
"error": {
      "message": "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}
```

How can I give my app authorization to post to my fun page ?
thanks in advance

following recommendation of

Comment: Here is similar discussion to post photo to facebook instead of article.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474367/upload-photo-to-facebook-with-httpclient

Answer (score 15):

Wow, I see this same question asked at least once a day.

You will want to ask for `manage_pages` and `publish_stream`.  Once the admin of the page authenticates, query `me/accounts` and grab the page's access token from that list.  Using that page's access token, then you can post to `me/feed`.

Comment: I got access_token after admin authenticate application, but the message is posted as "admin" not "as page", this is important to show updates to people that likes my page. Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm, below you say just the opposite is what you're looking for "*But still have problem : sent post is "as administrator" not "as page"*"  So which is it?  Posting it as a page to the page, or as the admin to the page?

Comment: problem solved. I was able to post to page as page not as admin. I put an explaining note above. thx.

Comment: yes, this is what I described in my answer.  How to post to the page as the page.  :)  This question is asked about once a day on average on SO. :O

Comment: The key here is the "publish_stream" and "manage_pages" perms. With only "manage_pages" you'll get a bounce.

Answer (score 2):

simple, u just need to ask permissions..that's it..

```
String[] permissions = { "offline_access", "publish_stream", "user_photos", "publish_checkins","photo_upload" };
mFacebook.authorize(MainActivity.this, permissions,
            new LoginDialogListener());
```

Comment: It's worked in my case too but Where to place this code. And how to know that user already permitted this or not.

Comment: @KrishnakantDalal i did not get "where to place this code" . And Facebook UI will ask the permissions to the user when he first tries to login using Facebook. And it asks only once.

Answer (score 0):

You're using application `access_token` while you should use `access_token` for user or page.

- User's `access_token` is present within [`signed_request`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) (in cookie, or passed to application canvas).
- Page `access_token` available in `accounts` connection of [`user`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) once user granted `manage_pages` permission to your app.

**Update:**
To post as Administrator you'll need the user's access_token.
To post as Page you'll need page `access_token`

Comment: I got a user access_token for page administrator using url : http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?scope=manage_pages,publish_stream,offline_access&client_id=APP_ID&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cercleimmobilier.ma&response_type=token, then the post goes to page wall. But still have problem : sent post is "as administrator" not "as page" so it doesn't appear on people who likes my fun page, it appears on "Everyone (Most Recent)"

Comment: should use "page access token" as descr ibe in facebook doc page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/ instead of user (admin) access token. Thanks Juicy Scripter

Answer (score 0):

Facebook has changed the `publish_stream` permission to `publish_actions`. So you need to apply both `publish_actions` and `manage_pages` permissions.